# meteor dynamic dropdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, meteor, semantic-ui

I'am using Semantic-Ui.
Now I have problems with the dropdown.

The Dropdown get populated dynamically with values from the minimongo.

When I do $('.menu').dropdown() in myTemplate.rendered it thinks the Dropdown is empty and it doesn't work but when i put it in dropdowntListItems.rendered it get called N times. N is the count() of the items.

This solution works.
Is there a better solution for that?

```
//myTemplate
<div class="menu">
    {{#each dropdowntList}} 
        {{> dropdowntListItems}}
    {{/each}}
 </div>

 <template name="dropdowntListItems">
     <div class="item">{{item}}</div>
 </template>
```

```js
Template.myTemplate.dropdowntList = function (){
    return Items().fetch();
};

Template.dropdowntListItems.rendered = function(){
    $('.menu').dropdown(); //gets called N times
};
```

Comment: shouldn't it be Items().find() instead

Answer (score 3):

This took me forever to get - probably because I got confused with template names somehow, but here’s how I created a dropdown list of vendor names, populated from a MongoDB collection, using Meteor.js and Semantic-Ui:

First, create your templates for the dropdown list and the items it will contain:

```
<template name="vendorNames">
  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="vendor">
    <div class="default text">Vendor</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      {{# each vendorNames}}
        {{> vendorName}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="vendorName">
  <div class="item" name="vendor">{{name}}</div>
</template>
```

Then, make sure the jQuery for the dropdown works and get the list of vendors in `vendor_names.js`

```
// Activate semantic-ui jQuery for drop down
Template.vendorNames.rendered = function() {
  $('.ui.selection.dropdown')
    .dropdown('restore default text')
    ;
}
// Add the template helper to get the Vendors list
Template.vendorNames.helpers({
  vendorNames: function() {
    return Vendors.find();
  }
});
```

It's not dramatically different from the first answer, but I couldn't get that answer to work for me.  I'm pretty new to Meteor and programming in general so I was likely just missing something simple.  Either way, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is the good solution. Since Blaze has been released, [the rendered callback is only triggered once](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#rendered-callback-only-fires-once).

In `Template.myTemplate.rendered`, the dropdown is empty because the rendered callback is triggered before `Items().fetch()` in `Template.myTemplate.dropdownList` is completely run. Besides, when a new item is added, another problem would be that the dropdown will not be updated.

Avital, who is part of the MDG and have worked on the new Blaze engine, [have uploaded two different solutions](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback) on how to achieve the same behavior as the old rendered callback (before Blaze).

1: [By adding a new helper](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback/tree/master/new1).

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <div class="menu">
        {{#each dropdowntList}} 
            {{item}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>


Template.myTemplate.item = function (){
    $('.menu').dropdown();
};
```

2: [By Wrapping the contents of #each in a template](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback/tree/master/new2). (what you did)

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <div class="menu">
        {{#each dropdowntList}} 
            {{> dropdowntListItems}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="dropdowntListItems">
    <div class="item">{{item}}</div>
</template>

Template.dropdowntListItems.rendered = function(){
    $('.menu').dropdown(); //gets called N times
};
```